# Find out if a python script is running in IDLE or terminal/command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, cross-platform, python-idle

Is there a way to find out if the python script is running in the IDLE interpreter or the terminal?

Works cross-platform if possible, or if needed a different way for each platform.

Work with Python 2 and Python 3 if possible, or if needed a different way for each version.

The only way I could think of is checking the processes running for IDLE but I don't know how to do that right.

If IDLE is open for another script and my script is running in the terminal, a process check would return true even if my script is not running in the IDLE.

My script needs to run differently depending on if it is running in IDLE or a terminal.

Comment: Related : [What code can I use to check if Python is running in IDLE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431498/what-code-can-i-use-to-check-if-python-is-running-in-idle)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This *seems* to work on Python3/Linux

```
import sys

print("idlelib" in sys.modules)
```

If will return `True` if the script is run from Idle, `False` otherwise. Please test for other combination of Python/OS !

Comment: Works also on Python3/Windows.

Comment: Also works on Python 3 (macOS).

Comment: Still works on Python 3.10 / macOS 13

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077118/2544441:

```
sys.stdout.isatty()
```

is true if your script can write to a "true" terminal (at least since Python 2.7).