# Why is multiprocessing module not producing the desired result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrent-processing

[image]

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def cube(num):
    print(os.getpid())
    print("Cube is {}".format(num*num*num))

def square(num):
    print(os.getpid())
    print("Square is {}".format(num*num))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = mp.Process(target = cube, args = (3,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target = square, args = (4,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("Done")
```

[image]

I was using the **`multiprocessing`** module, but I am not able to print any output from a function using that.

I even tried flushing the `stdout` using the `sys` module.

Comment: `if _name_ == "_main_"` There should be _two_ underscores before and after `name` and `main`, not just one.

Comment: I tried that tooo....still didn't work sir

Comment: `_name_` should have produced an error, as no such variable exists.  That tells me this isn't your actual code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: This works on my Linux machine with Python 3.8.3. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198857/python-multiprocessing-example-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Why is `multiprocessing` module **not producing the desired result?**"*

Why?

Because it crashes.

The MWE/MCVE-representation of the problem has a wrong code. It crashes & it has nothing to do with the `sys.stdout.flush()` :

```
>>> cube(  4 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in cube
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

---

### Solution :

```
>>> import os   # be it in the __main__ or in the def()-ed functions...

>>> cube(  4 )
14165
Cube is 64
```

and your **`mp.Process()`**-based replicas of the python-process instances will stop crashing too.

---

### MCVE that works :

```
(base) Fri May 29 14:29:33 $ conda activate py3
(py3) Fri May 29 14:34:55 $ python StackOverflow_mp.py
This is ____6745::__main__
This is ____6746::PID
This is ____6747::PID
Cube(__3) is _______27.
Square(__4) is _______16.
Done.
Works.
Q.E.D.
```

---

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import sys
import time

def cube( num ):
    print( "This is {0:_>8d}::PID".format( os.getpid() ) )
    print( "Cube({0:_>3d}) is {1:_>9d}.".format( num, num*num*num ) )
    sys.stdout.flush()

def square( num ):
    print( "This is {0:_>8d}::PID".format( os.getpid() ) )
    print( "Square({0:_>3d}) is {1:_>9d}.".format( num, num*num ) )
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print( "This is {0:_>8d}::__main__".format( os.getpid() ) )
    p1 = mp.Process( target = cube,   args = (3, ) )
    p2 = mp.Process( target = square, args = (4, ) )
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    time.sleep( 1 )

    print( "Done.\nWorks.\nQ.E.D." )
```

---

> <sub>*I copied and pasted your exact code. But I still didn't get the output from the called functions using the multiprocessing libraries
> – [Kartikeya Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13195305/kartikeya-agarwal) [47 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067188/why-is-multiprocessing-module-not-producing-the-desired-result/62071647?noredirect=1#comment109817344_62071647)*</sub>

So,
- I opened a new Terminal process,
- I copied the `conda activate py3` command and
- I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let it run, so as to make `python3` ecosystem go live.
- I re-launched the proof-of-solution again `python StackOverflow_mp.py` and
- I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let it run
- I saw it working the very same way as it worked last time.
- I doubt the problem is on the provided twice (re)-validated proof-of-solution side, is it?
**Q.E.D.**

```
(py3) Fri May 29 19:53:58 $ python StackOverflow_mp.py
This is ___27202::__main__
This is ___27203::PID
Cube(__3) is _______27.
This is ___27204::PID
Square(__4) is _______16.
Done
```

Comment: Sir, it is working without the multiprocessing libraries but as soon as I try to divide the work between the CPU's. it stops giving the o/p.
I am using JupiterNotebook to interpret python if it has anything to do with it

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact code. But I still didn't get the output from the called functions using the multiprocessing libraries