# Printing issue in multiprocess - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing because I've a problem with my code. I created a main script in which running 5 child processes that comunicate with event objects.
All child processes have printing to debug their information ( I used function : print("",flush=True)).
All processes have a while loop that I kill with an event object when I want to exit.
In one of these processes I inserted a tkinter GUI with several buttons that manages some event objects.
When I run the script with all child processes except the process with tkinter Gui all printing are represented in the console and if then I stop the running, enable the tkinter process and re-start the running all printing are represented, but if I run all processes at first time info no printing are represented (all processes perfectly work because I debugged it by writeline in a txt file during this issue).
Moreover, if the printing has this issue I must restart the pc and then the code without tkinter process before see the printing.

Does tkinter interact with the printing on console? It's strange that if tkinter process immediately runs ,it generates this problem.

Thanks for your attention.

Best regards

Matteo Padalino

Ps: Windows 10 - Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 05:59:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.33.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

---

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198857/python-multiprocessing-example-not-working)

Comment: Related :https://stackoverflow.com/q/35293178